# Drag & Drop HTML editor as MailChimp Editor

Tags: php, html-editor, drag-drop

I have an email marketing platform, and im LF an drag and drop html editor for bulletins, do you know any open source with backend for php?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i have a fork of a opensource script in github for creat html by drag and drop

you can use this

https://github.com/komeilkma/VvvebJs

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer, how can i start learning about this ? what technologys do you use?

Comment: I already know PHP and some of JavaScript, but idk if I must use a especific library or framework

Comment: There is a complete guide and doc in the github for this framework

Comment: But this is not only for email marketing newsletters